# Converting Array of CartesianIndex to 2D-Matrix in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

let's say we have an array of cartesian indices in Julia

```
julia> typeof(indx)
Array{CartesianIndex{2},1}
```

Now we want to plot them as a scatter-plot using PyPlot. so we should convert the *indx*-Array of Cartesian to a 2D-Matrix so we can plot it like this:

```
PyPlot.scatter(indx[:, 1], indx[:, 2])
```

How can i convert an Array of type *Array{CartesianIndex{2},1}* to a 2D-Matrix of type *Array{Int,2}*

By the way here is a code snippet how to produce a dummy Array of cartesianindex:

```
A = rand(1:10, 5, 5)
indx = findall(a -> a .> 5, A) 
typeof(indx) # this is an Array{CartesianIndex{2},1}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure: a `CartesianIndex` has not much to do with a "cartesian coordinate". It is a special internal representation of an N-dimensional index in an array. Are you sure that you want to plot the indices themselves?

Comment: @phg I strongly disagree. A `CartesianIndex` is _precisely_ the cartesian coordinate into a matrix. Of course, if you plot it with a normal y-axis it'll be upside down, but that's an easy fix.  It's not an internal representation at all — we fully expect folks to work with them directly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way is `hcat(getindex.(indx, 1), getindex.(indx,2))`

```
julia> @btime hcat(getindex.($indx, 1), getindex.($indx,2))
  167.372 ns (6 allocations: 656 bytes)
10×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  1
 3  2
 4  2
 1  3
 4  3
 5  3
 2  4
 5  4
 1  5
 4  5
```

However, note that you don't need to - and therefore probably shouldn't - bring your indices to 2D-Matrix form. You could simply do

```
PyPlot.scatter(getindex.(indx, 1), getindex.(indx, 2))
```

Comment: Looks like you dont need hcat  `getindex.(indx, [1 2])` would give both dimensions

Answer (score 8):

An easy and generic way is

```
julia> as_ints(a::AbstractArray{CartesianIndex{L}}) where L = reshape(reinterpret(Int, a), (L, size(a)...))
as_ints (generic function with 1 method)

julia> as_ints(indx)
2×9 reshape(reinterpret(Int64, ::Array{CartesianIndex{2},1}), 2, 9) with eltype Int64:
 1  3  4  1  2  4  1  1  4
 2  2  2  3  3  3  4  5  5
```

This works for any dimensionality, making the first dimension the index into the CartesianIndex.