# Converting Array of CartesianIndex to 2D-Matrix in Julia using as_ints

Tags: arrays, julia

I am writing a program to extract specific elements of an array of type **Array{Union{Missing, Float64},2}** using findall; 
findall returns a variable **Array{CartesianIndex{2},1};** .

I try to convert this variable into a standard matrix using as_ints as explained in :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300691/9130305

I get an error message :

> ERROR: UndefVarError: as_ints not defined

Does this function still exist in Julia Version 1.1.0? If YES how can I use it?
Thanks for your help.

I use Julia in Atom on MacBook Pro

Code I use
...

```
indices = findall(x -> x == 4000,data);

ind = as_ints(indices);

...
```

Comment: That post *defined* the `as_ints` function. You can just copy/paste it. But broadcasting `getindex` works too!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to get exactly, but this is probably what you are looking for:

```
julia> x = rand(5,5)
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.162856  0.19944   0.497173  0.644154  0.0535536
 0.249625  0.86901   0.451791  0.614897  0.185165
 0.674177  0.995515  0.261636  0.705788  0.410553
 0.029235  0.743839  0.672526  0.489376  0.0748679
 0.980195  0.892695  0.531932  0.493069  0.683519

julia> c = findall(t->t<0.5, x)
13-element Array{CartesianIndex{2},1}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1)
 CartesianIndex(2, 1)
 CartesianIndex(4, 1)
 CartesianIndex(1, 2)
 CartesianIndex(1, 3)
 CartesianIndex(2, 3)
 CartesianIndex(3, 3)
 CartesianIndex(4, 4)
 CartesianIndex(5, 4)
 CartesianIndex(1, 5)
 CartesianIndex(2, 5)
 CartesianIndex(3, 5)
 CartesianIndex(4, 5)

julia> getindex.(c, [1 2])
13×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
 2  1
 4  1
 1  2
 1  3
 2  3
 3  3
 4  4
 5  4
 1  5
 2  5
 3  5
 4  5
```

In short - you can broadcast `getindex` over a vector of `CartesianIndex` entries and select in columns the indices that you want to get.

Is this what you are looking for?

(and this is essentially the same what crstnbr has written in [Converting Array of CartesianIndex to 2D-Matrix in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54256481/converting-array-of-cartesianindex-to-2d-matrix-in-julia/54300691#54300691) by as I see now)

Comment: Thanks also ... that's what I need!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are saying you want to extract elements from a matrix using `findall`. Unless I misunderstand, you don't *need* to convert the `CartesianIndex`es to an array. Just use them directly to retrieve the elements. For example:

```
A = rand(5, 4) # source array
f = x -> x >= 0.7 # filtering function
ind = findall(f, A)  # returns vector of CartesianIndex
elements = A[ind]  # retrieve elements
```

No need to convert, this is what `CartesianIndex` is *for*.

Alternatively, you can use logical indexing to get the elements:

```
elements = A[f.(A)]
```

or filtering:

```
elements = filter(f, A)
```

or a comprehension:

```
elements = [a for a in A if f(a)]
```

As for the `to_ints` function from the linked post, that never existed in Julia. It was a function that the poster defined right there in the post, in order to show how it could be done. But I suspect you don't need it at all.